# What can cause an Excel status bar quick sum calculation to be wrong?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have selected a **5 column by 20 row block** in an **Excel 2003 SP3** spreadsheet.  I have selected **Sum** from the quick calc options in the **status bar**.  However, the status bar shows a total of £24,000 when it should be ~12,000.  **The Sum calculation is wrong.**

I have done the following to try and diagnose the cause:

- Reviewed each cell in the selection for a value hidden by colour formatting (none).
- Tried to Unhide any potentially hidden rows.
- Reviewed the selection for rogue formulas (none).
- Copied the data to a new sheet and tried the same Sum.  **This works correctly!**
- Quick summed each 1*20 column in turn (individually they sum correctly).

**Question:  What are ALL of the potential causes of such an incorrect calculation?**

Comment: What version of MS office are you using

Comment: @Dheer Thanks for pointing that out.  I have added the version to the Q.  Excel 2003 SP3.

Comment: when you actually look at the formula does it match what it would if you explicitly declared it? e.g. =sum("A1:E20")

Comment: You've checked for hidden rows, are there any hidden columns?

Comment: @Diem *blush* I did have a hidden column :(  Thanks for the tip, not sure why I didn't check that!  So what do we do about the answer?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? If it's using the status bar to confirm that the totals match something else, you could Ctrl+click the column headers to just calculate the visible columns. Alternatively, you can use the worksheet function SUBTOTAL which I believe will sum the visible cells. =SUBTOTAL(9,_range_)

Comment: @bentayloruk in that case write your own answer to not only check for hidden rows but also for hidden columns :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following things can cause the quick sum calculation to be wrong:

- Hidden rows
- Hidden columns

[How to show or hide columns and rows in Excel](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/show-or-hide-columns-and-rows-HP001217049.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HA010241040)

*Note:  my problem was caused by a hidden column *embarrassed look*.  Thanks to @Diem for pointing this out in the question comments.  In the absence of any other correct answers, I will mark this as the answer for now.*

Answer (score -1):

This may be a numerical accuracy issue. Spreadsheet software are known for poor numerical accuracy, see http://www.jstatsoft.org/v34/i04/paper.

Comment: There's a slight difference between `numerical accuracy/floating point precision` and `being of by 100 percent`.